# Ropsten contract doesn't send anything when calling with this.balance after initialized with eth

Tags: contract-invocation, ropsten

This was my code:

```
contract Oust {
    address kingdom = 0x344d65e66a9c4f8d7911bf7433b509d6daac9bc0;
  function Oust() public payable {

  }    

  function take() public {

      kingdom.call.value(this.balance);
  }
```

I initialized it with 1.5 eth on Ropsten, but when calling "take", the transction is made with 0 value}

instead of 1.5:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x31ee35d188c3f7ced8c4af85de55392e3946a705

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line isn't actually doing anything:

```
kingdom.call.value(this.balance);
```

It should be:

```
kingdom.call.value(this.balance)();
```

or better yet:

```
kingdom.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

`this.balance` is deprecated in favor of `address(this).balance`, and `transfer` is superior to `call` because it `revert`s if the transfer fails.